# how to add "thumbs" befor last part of image url with php?

Tags: php, url, thumbnails

my url is Like this:

`http://mydomain/filemanager/photos/shares/xxxx/image.jpg`

I need convert this image url to:
`http://mydomain/filemanager/photos/shares/xxxx/thumbs/image.jpg`

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what the filename (i.e. `image.jpg`) is:

`str_replace('image.jpg', 'thumbs/image.jpg', $fullPath)`

Finding out the filename is fairly easy:

`basename($fullPath)`

**Putting it together**

```
$fileName = basename($fullPath);
$newFileName = 'thumbs/' . $filename;
$newPath = str_replace($filename, $newFileName, $fullPath);
```